# Regex search-and-replace in database tables

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm using PHP and MySQL. Imagine a series of articles that all include the following HTML code:

```
</div>
<div id="Homes">
  <h2>Homes</h2>
```

However, there could be differences in whitespace, like this:

```
</div>
[WHITESPACE]
<div id="Homes"><h2>Homes</h2>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to use regular expressions to insert something before the first div closing tag in the example above, like this:

```
[INSERT SOMETHING HERE]
</div>
<div id="Homes">
  <h2>Homes</h2
```

The regular expression would ignore whitespace and target the last div closing tag before div#Homes.

If you don't know the exact regular expression that would do this, that's fine. I just need to know if it can be done (and whether it can be done with phpMyAdmin or if I need a different program).

If it CANNOT be done, then I'm going to have to insert some code that can be replaced with str_replace. But it would be a lot simpler and cleaner if I could use regular expressions.

P.S. My page will actually include several similar divs/headings - Homes, Ecology, Environment, etc. I'd like to be able to insert content or features at the end of each section - but before the closing div tag in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
</div>(?=[\s\n\r]+<div id="Homes">)
```

Then replace with

```
[INSERT SOMETHING HERE]\n</div>
```

This will match the last `</div>` before the Homes div, not matter the number of newlines or whitespaces.

```
</div>
<div id="Homes">
  <h2>Homes</h2>
```

Explanation of regex:

- `</div>` match the `</div>`
- `?=` is a forward lookup. Note that this is non capturing, and it will not be part of the match
- `[\s\n\r]` match a whitespace or newline character

If you also want to match when everything is on one line then you would just replace `+` with `*`:

```
</div>(?=[\s\n\r]*<div id="Homes">)
```

matches the `<\div>` in

```
</div><div id="Homes"><h2>Homes</h2><div id="Homes">
```